# Error when deploying Rails app to heroku (could not create resource with vendor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I want to develop a little Rails application and to deploy it to Heroku.
It is the second time I use Heroku but the first time I did not have problems

This time, when I tried to deploy it with this command line:

```
git push origin master
```

I had this:

```
Counting objects: 73, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 27.16 KiB, done.
Total 73 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -- binstubs bin/ --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Installing rake (10.0.3)
   Installing i18n (0.6.1)
   Installing multi_json (1.5.0)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.9)
   Installing builder (3.0.4)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.9)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing rack (1.4.3)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing hike (1.2.1)
   Installing tilt (1.3.3)
   Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.9)
   Installing mime-types (1.19)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing treetop (1.4.12)
   Installing mail (2.4.4)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.9)
   Installing arel (3.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.9)
   Installing activeresource (3.2.9)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
   Installing execjs (1.4.0)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
   Installing json (1.7.6)
   Installing rdoc (3.12)
   Installing thor (0.16.0)
   Installing railties (3.2.9)
   Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Installing daemons (1.1.9)
   Installing eventmachine (1.0.0)
   Installing jquery-rails (2.1.4)
   Installing pg (0.14.1)
   Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.2)
   Installing rails (3.2.9)
   Installing sass (3.2.5)
   Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
   Installing thin (1.5.0)
   Installing uglifier (1.3.0)
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Post-install message from rdoc:
   Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
   <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
   = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
   = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
   >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   Asset precompilation completed (11.92s)
-----> Rails plugin injection
   Injecting rails_log_stdout
   Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types      -> (none)
   Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size: 10.1MB
-----> Launching... !     Heroku push rejected, Could not create resource with vendor, please try again later

To git@heroku.com:stage-2013.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stage-2013.git'
```

In .git/config I have this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@heroku.com:stage-2013.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
push = +HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

If someone have an idea, thanks for help

Comment: I'm also having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a Vendor (Heroku) problem not our problem.

Comment: My deploy worked this morning. I did nothing special. Probably Heroku problem